# Entity Framework and Template 10 - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: windows, entity-framework, uwp, template10

I am trying to get the tutorial on https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/uwp/getting-started.html working using a Template 10 blank app template but the migration fails when I try `Add-Migration MyFirstMigration` and get the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. When I try this in a regular blank app it works perfectly but not with the other template. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: are you using Rc2 of EF?

Comment: Apparently I am. (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite 1.0.0-rc2-final)

Comment: I have seen this but it didn't matter if it was template10 or standard uwp app

Comment: more than likely a EFC issue